# Cut and paste in a for loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I am trying to cut and paste values within a for loop from one list to another.  I have the range all set up but for some reason the `paste` keeps failing and I'm not sure why. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
If WrdArray1(0) = WrdArray2(0) Then
ActiveCell.Cut
With ActiveSheet
Set rng2 = .Range("C" & position)
rng2.PasteSpecial
End With
```

I am rather new to vba so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what the Error you are getting and

Comment: It just says "PasteSpecial method of range class failed"

Comment: Have you tried just `.Paste` instead of `.PasteSpecial` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ActiveCell.Cut Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("C" & position)`. That does all in one.